# How to retrieve current form data's last modified time?

Tags: orbeon

Is there a way to retrieve the current form data's last modified time when the existing form is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately currently not. The information is not propagated from the persistence layer. I added an [RFE for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2952).